# TreeView1_NodeCheck compile error : procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Tags: vba, treeview

I am trying to check/uncheck the children and subchildren if the parent node is checked. Also, the parent node gets checked if one of the children / subchildren is checked.

My code works in my computer.

In another PC it shows

> "compile error : procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

The error happens on the procedure declaration itself.

Here is the code:

```vb
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)

Dim iChild, yChild As Integer
Dim nodX, nodY As Node

    If Node.Children <> 0 Then
    'if there are children present, then Node is a parent
        Set nodX = Node.Child
        For iChild = 1 To Node.Children
            nodX.Checked = Node.Checked
            
            If nodX.Children <> 0 Then
            'if there are children present, then node is a child with subchildren
                Set nodY = nodX.Child
                For yChild = 1 To nodX.Children
                    nodY.Checked = nodX.Checked
                    Set nodY = nodY.Next
                    'if a subchild is checked, then nodX, which is a child, should be checked
                    'do this loop to check if any of the subchildren is checked, then check the child
                Next
             End If
            'if a child is checked, then Node, which is a parent, should be checked
            'do this loop to check if any of the children is checked, then check the parent
            Set nodX = nodX.Next
        Next
    Else
        If Not Node.Parent Is Nothing Then
        'if the parent of the Node does exist, then it is a child
            If Node.Checked Then
                'check the parent and skip the loop if the current node is checked.
                Node.Parent.Checked = True
            Else
                Node.Parent.Checked = False
                'if the Node, which is a child, is unchecked, then uncheck the parent
                'however, proceed with the loop below to see if other children are checked. If yes, check the parent
                Set nodX = Node.Parent.Child
                Do Until nodX Is Nothing
                    If nodX.Checked Then
                        'at least one other child node is checked so check the parent and exit the loop
                         Node.Parent.Checked = True
                         Exit Do
                     End If
                     Set nodX = nodX.Next
                Loop
            End If
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

I picked the event from the dropdown boxes of VBA.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vba having always used VB6 here, but my guess is that your other machine is using an earlier version of the Windows Common Controls OCX. (comctl32.ocx). The later version is MsCommCtl.ocx and it does use the procedure declaration that you have in your code whereas the earlier version uses: Private Sub TVw_NodeCheck(ByVal Node As Node). - Spot the difference!

Comment: On reflection, I don't think that the older version of the control supports checkboxes anyhow!

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for your reply! I tried to debug on the other PC, and just rewrite the event using the dropdown boxes, and it basically just re-wrote the same exact event handler, and it then worked! Does this mean that this other computer also uses MsCommCtl.ocx as well?

But when I now sent this file to the original PC where it used to work, the same error was passed on to this one now.. I really do not know what causes this :(

Comment: It does sound as if you have the correct OCX on the other machine, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to guess what the problem might be. The only thing I can suggest is that you save the code from each machine as text and run a comparison between them if possible.